AUC-ROC Comparison and Intepretation if FPR < 1
I am comparing two unsupervised models that predict a binary class, each with a different threshold parameter (p for model A and g for model B, ranging from 0 to 1).
You can see that Model B has no monotonic ordering in PR trade-offs (correct behavior due to some approximations that I am researching) but generally fits closer to an ideal model at TPR=1 and FPR=0 (yellow dot).
My "issue" is that model B (regardless of value-setting g) never reaches a theoretical FPR=1. This is not bad, as no matter the value of g, there is always some TN in the denominator. However, if I compute the ROC-AUC (using numpy.trapz in Python) of the overall discriminative power, Model B is losing.
I thought about smoothing the curve, but I am not sure it is the right thing.
How can I "academically correct" compare both models using AUC ROC?
I want to avoid cherry-picking the new proposed Model B :-)


I don't know what you show on the right side for model B. That's for sure not a ROC  curve.

@Calimo, please explain why this is not a ROC curve :D?

A ROC curve is monotonous by definition. You cannot have a non monotonous ROC curve.

My parameter in Model B approximates a fixed threshold. I can sort it to make it monotonous - I did it for smoothing. Should this matter for AUC?

To draw a ROC curve you vary the decision threshold, keeping parameters fixed.

Model B's parameters are fixed, and the decision threshold varies. The non-monotonous behavior can occur if models are non-linear, as in my case.
I do not feel like justifying the monotonicity but rather the AUC interpretation of models that never have an FPR < 1 regardless of the decision threshold. Still, thank you for your comments.
